# Cytoscape: How to add background image to node using relative path like '../images/test.jpeg'?

Tags: image, cytoscape

I am trying to build up a flowchart using Cytoscape.js. Can anyone tell me how to set 'background-image' from a local file system path?

Thanks in advance.
Kejal

Comment: please post an example of code.

Comment: We want to use image from "C:/images/Test.jpg" instead of any url..selector('.option')
                .css({
                  'background-image': 'https://farm7.staticflickr.com/6098/6224655456_f4c3c98589_b.jpg'
                })

Comment: Any comments on how to resolve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This issue gets resolved in ReactJS by importing image reference instead of adding path like `C:\test.jpg`, we need to add it like:

```
import test from './test.jpg'

.selector('.option') 
.css({ 
'background-image': test; 
})
```