# How to use a local background image with Dash Cytoscape?

Tags: javascript, python, html, plotly-dash, cytoscape.js

How to use a local image as a node background image with Dash Cytoscape?
I can only make it work with an online image, with a `https` path.

I have tried `'background-image': 'file:///C:/path/image.png'` and `'background-image': './image.png'` but it doesn't work, there is no image on the graph.

I have read the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45672565/cytoscape-how-to-add-background-image-to-node-using-relative-path-like-imag), but it doesn't solve my problem as I want to specify the image location as a node property, without having to update the stylesheet for every new node.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue recently and could find a workaround using the dash assets system (https://community.plotly.com/t/adding-local-image/4896/9)

1. Create a folder called 'assets' in the same folder of your cytoscape.py and place your picture 'my-image.png' on that folder
2. Add the parameter to your selector on the stylesheet: `'background-image':app.get_asset_url('my-image.png')`

Answer (score 0):

For me it also works if you just put `'background-image': 'url(/assets/my-image.png)'` in the style property of the cytoscape element. This is useful if you create the dash elements in another file and don't have the app-object there.

```
cyto.Cytoscape(
    id = 'cyto1',
    elements = edges + nodes,
    style = {'background-image': 'url(/assets/my-image.png)'}
)
```